For Next Loop with Step 0.001 Creating More Output Values Than Expected
This VBA code is producing what seems like an endless amount of values. I had to stop it because it was going for so long.
I expected it to produce 2626 values (2.626/0.001) in the active cell column.
Sub simp3()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim max1 As Long
    Dim max2 As Long
    Dim r1 As Range
    Dim r2 As Range
    Set r1 = Range("AP7:AP26500")
    Set r2 = Range("AS7:AS2633")
    
    Range("AS7").Select
    
    For i = 0 To 2.626 Step 0.001
        Range("C32") = i
        max1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.max(r1)
        ActiveCell.Value = max1
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Next i
    
    max2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.max(r2)
    Range("AS3").Value = max2

End Sub


You defined i as a  variable with data type long, so it will be casted to long and 0 + 0.001 will be 0 again. Just define it as Dim i as double.

The reason for the behaviour is that implicit conversion is taking place.
As you defined i as a variable with data type long, operations like 0 + 0.001 will be casted to long and therefore i = i + 0.001 will be 0 again. You have created an endless loop.
Just use Dim i as double
https://bettersolutions.com/vba/data-types/converting.htm
Check this example
   Sub implcitConversions()
    
    Dim i As Long
    i = 1
    i = i + 0.01
    ' Output will be 1 as 1 + 00.1 was converted to long by rounding
    Debug.Print i
    
    i = 1
    ' Output will be 1.01 as in this case
    ' a widening takes place due to the use of debug.print
    Debug.Print i + 0.01

End Sub


You are trying to iterate with a variable declared as Long using floating-point arithmetic. It would be cleaner to iterate in integers up to 2626 and then divide the value by 1000 within the loop. Alternatively, declare i as a double instead of long. While iterating with floating-point numbers is possible in VBA, it is not considered clean practice. In other languages, only integer steps are sometimes allowed for iterations.

Getting Rid of Select and Active

The main reason for your code failing is discussed in the previous answers and comments.
The following shows how you can improve the readability and maintainability by using constants and variables (feel free to rename them as you see fit).
Not using Select and various flavors of Active will improve the code's efficiency (speed). It still can be improved by introducing an array to hold the resulting values and write them to the worksheet in one go.

Sub simp3()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const FIRST_NUMBER As Double = 0 ' maybe 0.001 !?
    Const LAST_NUMBER As Double = 2.626
    Const STEP_NUMBER As Double = 0.001
    
    ' Reference the worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!

    ' Reference the source range.
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = ws.Range("AP7:AP26500")
    ' Reference the source trigger cell, a cell the values in the source range
    ' depend on.
    Dim scell As Range: Set scell = ws.Range("C32")
    
    ' Reference the destination first cell.
    Dim dfcell As Range: Set dfcell = ws.Range("AS7")
    ' Reference the destination max cell.
    Dim dmcell As Range: Set dmcell = ws.Range("AS3")
    ' Reference the next destination cell.
    ' We need the first destination cell to build the destination range ('drg')
    ' to get the destination max.
    Dim dcell As Range: Set dcell = dfcell
     
    Dim i As Double
    
    For i = FIRST_NUMBER To LAST_NUMBER Step STEP_NUMBER
        ' Trigger a change in the source range.
        scell.Value = i
        ' Write the new source max to the current destination cell.
        dcell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(srg)
        ' Reference the next destination cell (row).
        Set dcell = dcell.Offset(1)
    Next i
    
    ' Reference the destination range.
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = ws.Range(dfcell, dcell.Offset(-1))
    
    ' Write the destination max to the destination max cell.
    dmcell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(drg)

End Sub


Thanks a lot for the example. I'm a complete newbie to VBA so that was a great lesson. Just as a quick follow on, is there any reason I can't use a single in this situation?
